# How to get libraries for OrdImage

Tags: java, database, oracle, multimedia

I am trying to upload multimedia files into my Oracle DB. But I am unable to import `oracle.ord.im` libraries to get `OrdImage` class. I found out that `oracle.ord.im` is included in `ordim.jar`, but I am also unable to locate this file, or get any tip where to get it. I tied installing Oracle SQL developer, and also Oracle 12c with no luck.

Where can I get this package ?

Comment: Which version of Oracle 12c?

Comment: @APC 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by installing Oracle 11g database (11.2.0.1.0).